# Reload javascript resource programmatically in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to reload javascript resources programmatically in Chrome and if I run that from console, then it works fine, but if I put that into the code to reload after an event was fired, then the resource doesn't change. What is the problem?

I use this reloader:

```
var docHeadObj = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var dynamicScript = document.createElement("script");
dynamicScript.type = "text/javascript";
dynamicScript.src = 'js/resource.js';
docHeadObj.appendChild(dynamicScript);
```

And here is the event handler:

```
obj.onclick(function(){
    var docHeadObj = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var dynamicScript = document.createElement("script");
    dynamicScript.type = "text/javascript";
    dynamicScript.src = 'js/resource.js';
    docHeadObj.appendChild(dynamicScript);
});
```

After both cases the new and proper `<script>` element is appended to the `<head>` and on network tab the resource is downloaded, but in case of the second one the resource is never change.

EDIT:

I'm closer to the problem. If I have this code in the resource which will be reloaded `alert("aaa");`
And I open the application then after performing a click event I get an alert with 3 'a' letter. Then I decrease the number of the letters to 2, reload the resource, perform a click event, then I again see 3 'a' letter. Then I decrease the number of letters to 1, save and click, then I see 2 'a' letter. So it seems to be the Chrome (and also FF) stores the last modified resource except if I reload that from console.

Comment: You have to admit, that all events will be bind again.

Comment: I have several js resources and I don't reload the one which consists the handler.

Comment: do the file contents change between the script loads?

Comment: Yes, of course, it is the reason for reloading.

Comment: Have you tried adding a timestamp in the get parameters of the script? For example "resource.js?12358434"? Maybe it's a caching problem...

Answer (score 0):

You should wait before the script is loaded before you use it. It can be achieved with using `onload` event for the dynamic script

```
function loadScript(url, callback) {
    var docHeadObj = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var dynamicScript = document.createElement("script");
    dynamicScript.type = "text/javascript";
    dynamicScript.src = url;

    // bind the event to the callback function
    dynamicScript.onreadystatechange = callback; //for ie<9
    dynamicScript.onload = callback;

    // Fire the loading
    docHeadObj.appendChild(dynamicScript);
}


var testJQuery = function () {
    console.log($(this));
};

var obj = document.getElementById("test");
obj.onclick = function () {
    loadScript("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js", testJQuery);

};
```

[Working example on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darevskaya/CN3yQ/11/)

Answer (score 0):

If you just delete the last instance of the script tag before reloading it, that should force it to reload.

```
function load(link, id) {
    var exists = document.getElementById(id)
    if(exists){
        exists.parentNode.removeChild(exists);
    }
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = link;
    script.id = id;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
obj.onclick = function(){
    load('js/resource.js','dynamicScript')
}
```